# Net work being done on or by the gas and the user from a volume expansion, and how doing work affects the energy of ideal gas particles

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, work, conventions

My question is well-contained in the following exercise:

[image]

Here is my thought process:

- The enclosed volume is doubled, so the pressure decreased while the volume increased.
- Even though the pressure decreased, the average kinetic energy of each ideal gas particle hasn't been increased, as it hasn't been directly supplied energy - what this volume expansion has effectively done is increase the amount of time a particle moving in $+z$ will take before hitting a container. This strikes me as a free expansion, as the pressure has decreased and the volume increased without necessarily any change in kinetic energy of the gas particles and thus no temperature change.
- I use the sign convention for the first law of thermodynamics as $\Delta U = Q + W$.
- Since $W = -\int PdV$, and the volume change is positive, $dV$ has a positive signature, so $W$ is overall negative. This implies then, that work is being done by the system, and thus by the gas, and net work is being done on the user. This conclusion is basically a resuscitation and guess from lecture notes. My intuitive reasoning behind this is really bad.

I don't like how I thought this through, but this is what came up with. I'm not confident with the second and fourth bullet points in particular. To be honest, I can't imagine how any work can be done on the gas unless the particles are given energy. Here, to me changing the volume just changes the amount of space the particles have before colliding with the walls of the container.

Thus, my questions are two-fold:

- Is net work here being done on or by the gas inside the syringe? Is net work being done on or by the user? What about my thought processes are wrong?
- How can work change the internal energy of a system if it isn't directly increase the energy of the individual gas particles (perhaps I'm trying to get at saying - without heating the system?)?

I'm also inclined to think this is a free-expansion, as it seems to me this is merely a case where a partition is removed.

Comment: What direction is the force that the gas exerts on the piston?  How does this compare with the direction of the piston displacement?  What direction is the force that you have to exert on the piston?  How does that compare with the direction of the piston displacement?

Comment: The direction of force the gas exerts on the piston, if it is indeed exerting a force on the piston, would be in the direction it moved - so along $+z$. It should align with the direction of the piston's displacement, no? The direction of the force that I would have to exert on the piston... should be also to the right as well, which would also be the same direction as the piston displacement? Perhaps I'm wrong. I mean, the forces should align with the direction of the displacement, that would make sense.

Comment: This is all correct!!! So does the gas do work on the piston? And, do you do work on the piston?

Comment: I certainly do work on the piston by physically moving it to the right. And while I do agree with you that about the direction of the force the gas exerts on the piston and how it would be parallel to the displacement of the piston, I'm not yet convinced that the gas *actually* exerts a force on the piston to begin with, so I can't instantly say the gas does work on the piston.

Comment: Suppose that you are moving the piston very slowly, much more slowly than the gas molecules?  Certainly then you would agree that the gas is exerting a force on the piston,  After all, it would be exerting a force if it were not moving at all?  Do you really feel that there is a significant effect on the force if it moves at 1 cm per year compared to not moving at all?

Comment: Forgive me, I'm confused - are you saying if I moved the piston - increasing the volume extremely slowly, far slower than the speed of the ideal gas particles whizzing in the gas itself it would then be obvious the gas is exerting  a force on the piston? I don't see a clear implication from that. I'm confused with what the third sentence is saying as well. As for the last part, I don't see a huge difference in effect between a force that amounts in a movement of 1 $cm$ to no force at all, no. Do you mind clarifying?

Comment: If the piston was not moving, would you be comfortable saying that the gas is exerting a force on the piston?

Comment: No, I wouldn't, as the piston's momentum is not changing. However, I can accept the fact that some things can apply a pressure to something without moving it.

Comment: Wow.  I'm taken aback.  Even if the piston is not moving so that its momentum is not changing, the gas molecules are bouncing off the face of the piston, and their momentum is changing.  If the piston is moving very slowly and, of course, the gas molecules are moving very rapidly, do they continue to bounce off the face of the piston?  If you bounce a ball off a wall, with it exert a force on the wall?

Comment: If you bounce a ball off a wall, it will absolutely exert a force on it, by Newton's Third Law, yet the wall's momentum isn't changing. Hmm.

Comment: Who says that the wall's momentum isn't changing?  The wall is attached to the earth, and the momentum of the wall and earth change very slightly when the ball bounces off the wall. But I doubt this has much to do with the issue of whether a confined gas in a container is exerting a force on the walls of its container.  Anyway, initially, the air pressure on one side of the piston exerts a force on the piston that is equal and opposite to the force of the gas on the other side of the piston.  The two forces are  in balance, so there is no net force and no net acceleration (/momentum change).

Comment: Ah, so you're saying it *does* exert a force on the piston, but it distributes this force such that no net change in momentum is occurring. But that's initially. When the piston is pulled back, the volume increases, and the amount of particles hitting a wall of the container in a given increment of time decreases, so the pressure should decrease. However, I don't see the act of pulling it back doing work on the gas, nor do I see the gas doing work either.

Comment: If the gas is exerting a force on the piston while the piston is moving, then it is doing work on the piston.  If you are exerting a force on the piston while the piston is moving, then you are doing work on the piston (didn't you learn this in freshman physics?).  The outside atmosphere does negative work on the piston (or, equivalently, the piston does work on the outside atmosphere) as it moves in a direction opposite to the direction of the atmosphere's force.  For frictionless piston, the sum of the work you do, the work the gas does, and the work that the atmosphere does sums to zero.

Comment: Taking the idea that "If the gas is exerting a force on the piston while the piston is moving, then it is doing work on the piston." is less obvious to me than "If you are exerting a force on the piston while the piston is moving, then you are doing work on the piston". The question explicitly says I pull the piston. For all I know, the gas is, just as it was before, exerting forces on the sides of the piston evenly so its net force on the piston is $0$. The piston is now moving, yes, but I would naturally attribute it only to me pulling it, not gas particles moving it.

Comment: If it wasn't making the piston move before, and then I pull it back, how is the gas then responsible for the movement? I pulled it back using my own energy. The gas, for all it knows, I would think, just noticed it can go farther in its container before hitting the right-most end.

Comment: Basically, what I'm trying to say is even though the piston is moving, and has a force on it, the gas isn't necessarily doing work on it because I believe it's not giving the piston a net force, as you say here: the air pressure on one side of the piston exerts a force on the piston that is equal and opposite to the force of the gas on the other side of the piston." The only net force moving the system is my pulling it back only, I would think. I don't see how the gas particles are now hitting the container with a net force.

Comment: I’ve answeref as best I can, but I don’t seem to be getting through.  I think i’ll stop for now and give others a chance to answer.  Maybe they can articulate the concept better than I.